# Sharing a Tweet through DM using TweePy

Tags: python, tweepy

I was wondering if it is possible to "quote a tweet" through direct messages using TweePy. I know this can be done regularly in the Twitter app using the share feature but I was wondering if this could also be possible through Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy recommends that you [send](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) the [URL](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1192) of the tweet in a direct-message. https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/859

The URL will generate a formatted preview in the recipients inbox.